# Request for tag creation plus synonyms

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

Per discussion on [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17811/syntax-changes-between-db2-for-i-db2-400-v5r4-and-v6r1), could we add the tags ibm-i, as400, ibm-midrange, and even system-i and make them all synonyms of iseries?

Comment: Are we certain they will always be synonyms?

Comment: yes. they will always be synonyms.